# Where does my friend live? 5

Tags: knowledge, cipher, geography

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

One of my friends, Com, has sent me a code to show where he lives:

> ARIA, ---, ---, ESIA, ---, KAAN, KYAN, LAIA, ---, MOVA, RUIA, TAAN, TUAN, UKNE, ---

> 3, 15, 9, 5, 2, 11

**Can you figure out where he is?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your friend live in

> Bulgaria?

> As @Deepthinker has already mentioned, the rest of the countries are made from front 2 and back 2 letters from former Soviet Union countries:
>  **AR**MEN**IA** = ARIA 
>  **ES**TON**IA** = ESIA 
>  **KA**ZAKHST**AN** = KAAN 
>  **KY**RGYZST**AN** = KYAN 
>  **LA**TV**IA** = LAIA 
>  **MO**LDO**VA** = MOVA 
>  **RU**SS**IA** = RUIA 
>  **TA**JIKIST**AN** = TAAN 
>  **TU**RKMENIST**AN** = TUAN 
>  **UK**RAI**NE** = UKNE

> The missing five countries are therefore:
>  Azerbaijan 
>  Belarus 
>  Georgia 
>  Lithuania 
>  Uzbekistan

> Using the number hint, we just need to take the first letter of the country represented by that number in an alphabetical order. This spells out "BULGAR". These were members of a group of people living during the Middle Ages and a branch of this became the primary three ethnic ancestors of modern Bulgarians, as seen [here](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Bulgar). This means that Com probably live in "BULGARIA".

Answer (score 3):

> They the former countries of the USSR in alphabetical order.

> Armenia , Azerbaijan , Belarus, Estonia , Georgia , Kazakhstan , Kyrgyzstan , Latvia , Lithuania , Moldova, Russia , Tajikistan, Turkmenistan, Ukraine and Uzbekistan.

> these are the remaining countries it must be a cipher.

> Reason is that BEUS UZAN LIIA GEIA AZAN RUIA take the capitals of each.

> The answer is Bulgaria

> Com is a reference to communism.

Comment: But where does Com live?